# How to call a function or property in a LINQ Query Provider (ExpressionVisitor)

Tags: .net, linq, expressionvisitor

I am creating a LINQ Provider. And the query could look like this:

```
customers.Where( (f) => f.Date < DateTime.Now )
```

In my Query provider I Execute an ExpressionVisitor that reads the query and creates MSSQL queries. But I cannot find out how to Invoke the DateTime.Now property, when I am visiting the ExpressionTree.

When parsing the expressiontree I get the Expression Convert(Datetime.Now). I want to somehow call that property. So I later can append it to the generated sql query.
Above I had the query in C# syntax, although I code in VB.NET. The code is as below:

```
 Protected Overrides Function VisitBinary(expr As BinaryExpression) As Expression
    expr = ETH.ConvertVBStringCompare(expr)

    If (expr.Right.NodeType = ExpressionType.Convert) Then
        Dim a = ETH.CallIt(expr)
    End If
```

What it does is when I Expression.Right.NodeType is ExpresionType.Convert I step into an helper class:

```
Friend Shared Function CallIt(ByVal exp As BinaryExpression) As BinaryExpression

    If exp.Left.NodeType = ExpressionType.MemberAccess Then
        Dim compare = CType(exp.Left, MemberExpression)
        Dim compare1 = CType(exp.Right, UnaryExpression)
```

When I inspect the BinaryExpression I can see the f.Date on the Left side.
And If I convert the exp.Right to Unary I can see it as an Convert(DateTime.Now).
I need to invoke the DateTime.Now property somehow so I can append it later in the SQL Query.
Like this:

```
select * from customers where Date < "2018-05..."
```

I just cannot figure out how to invoke the property :(

**UPDATE:**
Okey, so I found out that the [msdn article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546158.aspx#Adding%20the%20Expression%20Evaluator) for creating an LINQ Provider has an example of an helper Class, a partial evaluator, that does this job for you. It goes trough the expression tree and evaluates function calls etc.
So I use that class in my project now. It's easier and it returns the Expression tree when it's done.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why I can't call a function inside a linq query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10161813/why-i-cant-call-a-function-inside-a-linq-query)

Comment: No this is not the same. I am writing my own provider. I could do whatever I want in theory. I just dont know how to invoke the Expression Convert (DateTime.Now) so i Can get the datetime.

Comment: what type is f.Date ?

Comment: It is DateTime .

Comment: Hmm. Think there seems to be a misunderstanding. I will update with some code ASAP. So it could be easier to understand my question :)

Comment: Okay Updated with code now :=)

Comment: Why not translate the `DateTime.Now` into the SQL equivalent rather than convert on the client side? BTW, what is the `Convert` converting to?

Comment: @NetMage Yes I was thinking about that too. But there might be other functions that does not exist in SQL Syntax that will be used so I need somehow to invoke anyway.

Comment: I dont actually know. That Convert is just there...

Comment: @FYI, it will be there because `f.Date` isn't a `DateTime` (it is probably a `DateTime?` if it is coming from a database) - you can see in the `Convert.Type` property what the `Convert` is actually doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a helper extension method for evaluating `Expression`s to get their value - you have to specify the return type since `Expression` doesn't have one.

```
public static T Evaluate<T>(this Expression e) {
    //A little optimization for constant expressions
    if (e.NodeType == ExpressionType.Constant)
        return (T)((ConstantExpression)e).Value;
    else
        return (T)Expression.Lambda(e).Compile().DynamicInvoke();
}
```

Comment: That did the trick. The Compile and DynamicInvoke()  thing was what I was looking for. Awesome. Have a great weekend sir!

Comment: I use it in an extension method that allows you to embed Expression references in labmda Expression bodies and then expand them out before running the query so LINQ can handle it - a sort of focused version of LINQKit's abilities.